# Debug OData requests

Tags: odata, sapui5

I am new to SAPUI5/OData development. So maybe this is a trivial question. To get a better feeling of what is going on I'd like to debug the OData requests executed from my application. How can I do this?

My environment:

- Eclipse with SAPUI5 tools
- Chrome for debugging
- Tomcat as Servlet Container.

I know how to start debugging tools in Chrome, I found the Network tab but what I wish to see is when the app is performing HTTP calls to the OData Service.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To debug an SAPUI5 Application, you can run it in debug mode by passing a debug paramter in the URL as below. The console will log all the debug events

```
...index.html?sap-ui-debug=true
```

You can also attach Event handlers to your OData model if you want to setup a Javascript breakpoint at the trigger of an OData call as documented [here](https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/#docs/api/symbols/sap.ui.model.odata.ODataModel.html)

```
oModel.attachRequestCompleted
oModel.attachRequestSent
```

Comment: Thanks! I was aware of the debug parameter but it did not show the oData requests. The hint with the model events did it. With a few lines of code I am logging the url now to the console.

Comment: if the answer solves you problem, can you may mark it as correct.