# How to see OData entity posting payload at a break-point within a SAPUI5 app

Tags: odata, sapui5

I would like to see the OData entity posting payload at a breakpoint (using Chrome developer tools) within a SAPUI5 app. I used the advice of [Debug OData requests](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42142344/debug-odata-requests) to add breakpoints within handlers for the RequestCompleted and RequestSent events. I searched within the Local portion and was unable to find the payload that accompanies a POST.  Does anyone know where I could find it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use the network tab, select a HTTP request and inspect the `Request Payload` section under the `Headers` tab.

[image]